# Check if functions are surjective

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am having trouble understanding surjection for this functions.

$f: \mathbb{N} \times\mathbb{N} → \mathbb{N}$

$f(n,m) = \min(n,m)$

I prove that it's a surjection:

$f(x)=k$

$f(k,k)=\min(k,k)=k$

But I am having issues with this one. This shows that it is not a surjection:

$f: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} → \mathbb{Z}$

$f(m,n) = m-n$

$f(x) = k$

$f(k,k) = k-k  ≠ k$

But in the answers it says it is, am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: How about $f(k,0)$?

Comment: You missunderstand the concept of surjection.

Comment: There is also a difference between "*this shows that it is not a surjection*" vs. "*this doesn't show that it is a surjection*". In fact, it is a surjection - just the proof you attempted doesn't show it: you need a different proof.

Comment: Ok so for the proof, I thought that I just need one example that shows it isn't. Didn't know I can choose any example that works.

Comment: If you are proving a statement "For every $x$ something happens" you need only one *counterexample* to prove the opposite. (Look, it *doesn't* happen for this $x$!!!) However, if your statement is of the form "there exists $x$ so that something happens" (which is what this is in a nutshell) then, to prove the opposite ("there isn't such $x$"), one example is obviously not enough.

Comment: Surjectivity is a statement of the form "for every $k$ there *exist* $x,y$ such that $f(x,y)=k$". In both cases the function is surjective and in the first case you prove it by example ($f(k,k)=k$) and you can do the same in the second case: $f(k, 0)=k$. What *you* did is (mostly) an attempt at a counterexample which is not enough to refute the statement: $f(k,k)$ may not be $k$, but $f(k,0)$ certainly is! (There are other possibilities for $x,y$ apart from the one you chose.)